# Better quote to execute command on shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm in doubt of the diference and which one is the better quote to execute a command in shell script.

For example, I have this two examples:

```
echo "The name of the computer is `uname -n`"
echo "The name of the computer is $(uname -n)"
```

Which one is better? Or there is no diference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$(...)` one is generally recommended because it nests easier. Compare:

```
date -d "1970-01-01 $(echo "$(date +%s)-3600"|bc) sec UTC"

date -d "1970-01-01 `echo \"\`date +%s\`-3600\"|bc` sec UTC "
```

Comment: +1 It's also easy to confuse backticks with single quotes at a quick glance. For more see [Why is $(...) preferred over backticks?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 "BashFAQ/082").